# What is the meaning of bold sentence in the paragraph given down below?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> "That’s where your friend is, floating up to Heaven,” was the answer.
> But I still did not understand until the truth was explained to me in
> plain words.
>
> **But I am telling things out of their turn. From a psychological point of view, we had a long, long way in front of us from the break of that dawn at the station until our first night’s rest at the camp.**

Excerpt From: Viktor E. Frankl. “Man's Search for Meaning.”

Comment: What didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I am telling things out of their turn.

He was telling the story, not in the proper time order.

> From a psychological point of view, we had a long, long way in front
> of us from the break of that dawn at the station until our first
> night’s rest at the camp.

He wants to explain what happened to arrive at the conversation on floating to heaven. And this is the introduction to the whole story.

It was only a day but he felt it was such a long day. The event goes from the station at dawn until they arrive at the camp and take rest at night.